# ZF2 Console: Route with name "xy" not found in Zend\Navigation\Page

Tags: console, zend-framework2

I wrote a module to generate sitemap xml files. I want to generate them in a console route via cronjob, but the problem is that I get an exception `Route with name "xy" not found` when I iterate through the navigation container. The route definitely exists. If I call it in a web request, everything works fine. The stack trace looks like the following:

```
======================================================================
 The application has thrown an exception!
======================================================================
 Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\RuntimeException
 Route with name "home" not found
----------------------------------------------------------------------
vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/SimpleRouteStack.php:328
#0 vendor/zendframework/zend-navigation/src/Page/Mvc.php(260): Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack->assemble(Array, Array)
#1 vendor/zendframework/zend-navigation/src/Page/AbstractPage.php(999): Zend\Navigation\Page\Mvc->getHref()
#2 vendor/zendframework/zend-navigation/src/Page/AbstractPage.php(1035): Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage->get('href')
#3 module/Sitemap/src/Sitemap/Service/GeneratorService.php(83): Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage->__get('href')
#4 module/Sitemap/src/Sitemap/Controller/Cli/GeneratorController.php(31): Sitemap\Service\GeneratorService->generateSitemaps()
#5 vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(82): Sitemap\Controller\Cli\GeneratorController->indexAction()
#6 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#8 vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(214): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#9 vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(93): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Console\Request), Object(Zend\Console\Response))
#11 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#12 vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#13 vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(214): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#14 vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(314): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#15 public/index.php(15): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#16 {main}
======================================================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the CLI to process or generate your sitemap XML and thus using another Router, the CLI one.

So you need to fetch the other Router class -> HTTP Router.

```php
array(
    // HttpRouter
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            // HTTP routes are here
        )
    ),
    // Console Router 
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(
                // Console routes go here
            )
        )
    ),
)
```

So in order to get the HttpRouter:

```
$serviceManager->get('HttpRouter')
```

So if you want to use the HttpRouter you can do the following within your CLI Controller(s):

```
$cliRouter = $this->getEvent()->getRouter();
$this->getEvent()->setRouter($httpRouter);
// Http Routers can be called with the plugins
$this->url()->fromRoute('home');
// Use CLI router again
$this->getEvent()->setRouter($cliRouter);
```

Calling `$this->url()->fromRoute('home');` this will throw your error in your question when using the CLI router. The "home" is not defined within your console routing and thus can not be found. Change your router to Http as you defined it in your HTTP routing.